# How can i track weights when i use tf.train.adamoptimizer

Tags: tensorflow

I am using tf.train.AdamOptimizer to train my neural network, I know I can train easily by this, but how can I track the weight changes, or is there any method and function for this job?

Thank you very much.

```
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=decoder.learning_rate).minimize(loss,global_step=global_step)
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example to print the weights of a layer of the model.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNetV2
print("Tensorflow Version:",tf.__version__)

model = MobileNetV2(input_shape=[128, 128, 3], include_top=False) #or whatever model
print("Layer of the model:",model.layers[2])
print("Weights of the Layer",model.layers[2].get_weights())
```

Output:
I have cut short the putput as the weights was lengthy.

```
Tensorflow Version: 1.15.0
Layer of the model: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7fe9123d2ac8>
Weights of the Layer [array([[[[ 1.60920480e-03, -1.45352582e-22,  1.54917374e-01,
           2.29649822e-06,  1.49279218e-02, -5.39761280e-21,
           7.01060288e-21,  1.54408276e-21, -1.12762444e-01,
          -2.37320393e-01,  2.77190953e-01,  5.03320247e-02,
          -4.21045721e-01,  1.73461720e-01, -5.35633206e-01,
          -5.95900055e-04,  5.34933396e-02,  2.24988922e-01,
          -1.49572559e-22,  2.20291526e-03, -5.38195252e-01,
          -2.21309029e-02, -4.88732375e-22, -3.89234926e-21,
           2.84152419e-22, -1.23437764e-02, -1.14439223e-02,
           1.46071922e-22, -4.24997229e-03, -2.48236431e-09,
          -4.64977883e-02, -3.43741417e-01],
         [ 1.25032081e-03, -2.00014382e-22,  2.32940048e-01,
           2.78269158e-06,  1.99653972e-02,  7.11864268e-20,
           6.08769832e-21,  2.95990709e-22, -2.76436746e-01,
          -5.15990913e-01,  6.78669810e-01,  3.02553400e-02,
          -7.55709827e-01,  3.29371482e-01, -9.70950842e-01,
          -3.02999169e-02,  7.99737051e-02, -4.45111930e-01,
          -2.01127320e-22,  1.61909293e-02,  2.13520035e-01,
           4.36614119e-02, -2.21765310e-22,  4.13772868e-21,
           2.79922130e-22,  4.81817983e-02, -2.71119680e-02,
           4.72275196e-22,  1.12856282e-02,  3.38369194e-10,
          -1.29655674e-01, -3.85710597e-01],
```